# Wifi drops out after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, upgrade

I have a laptop with an AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter. Running 14.04, it worked perfectly, and I rarely had any issues. However, I recently upgraded to 16.04, and now my wifi drops out every few minutes. It automatically reconnects a minute later, but it's really annoying. This happens with my home router, which is located three feet away and has full signal, so it's not a low signal problem.

How do I fix this? I've seen some similar posts about Realtek wifi adapters, but nothing for the AR9462.

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan1     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"mynetwork"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: 6F-6B-08-3B-17-46   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:71   Missed beacon:0

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Please edit to add result for `iwconfig`

Comment: @Jeremy31, Done.